# Fluent NHibernate Where Clause

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I have to write a query in Fluent NHibernate for

`Select * from Users where UserName = 'Abcd' AND Password = '123456'`

How to create above query with `session.CreateCriteria`

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Fluent NHibernate is a alternative Mapping framework to the default HBM files (Hibernate Mapping)

NHibernate itself offers different Querying API's like

- HQL - Hibernate Querying Language
- Criteria
- Query - (LINQ Equivalent)
- QueryOver - (strongly typed Criteria)
- SQL

For Criteria your query would be something along the lines of:

```
var users = session.CreateCriteria<Users>()
                   .Add(Restrictions.Eq("UserName", "Abcd"))
                   .Add(Restrictions.Eq("Password", "123456"))
                   .List<Users>();
```

Query:

```
var users = from u in session.Query<Users>()
            where u.UserName == "Abcd"
            && u.Password == "123456"
            select u;
```

or

```
var users = session.Query<Users>()
                   .Where(x => x.UserName == "Abcd" && u.Password == "123456");
```

QueryOver:

```
var users = session.QueryOver<Users>()
                   .Where(x => x.UserName == "Abcd")
                   .And(u.Password == "123456")
                   .List();
```

Comment: thanks for the great reply. Can i return a User as a type in the above queries ?

Comment: @Saad - A single user? Instead of a Collection? Sure. You can look at 'SingleOrDefault()' on the Query/QueryOver, instead of 'List()'. I'm not sure which method you call on the Criteria to do a single result. Don't have Visual Studio handy.

Comment: Can this be done in fluent mapping too? greatful if you could give an example of the same

Comment: @keyr - Fluent Mapping is just an in memory xml mapping. The mapping doesn't have any influence on your ability to run queries. Unless you get the mapping wrong.

Answer (score 0):

**Query Over**

```
var users = session.QueryOver<Users>()
                   .Where(x => x.UserName == "Abcd" && x.Password == "123456")
                   .List();
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IQuery:

```
User user = new User();
user.username="Abcd";
user.password="123456";

IQuery q = session.CreateQuery("from foo in class Foo where
user.username=:username and user.password=:password");
q.SetProperties(user);
var users= q.List<User>();
```